# Core Data and iCloud adding Pre-Populated sqlite file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, icloud

I'm working on an app that uses Core Data and iCloud to sync data between multiple iPads. This is all working fine and I can add data to each iPad and it will sync between them all.

I have a Core Data sqlite file that is pre-populated with a list of countries and I want to copy this to the documents area on first run of the app. I had this working but have changed my persistentStoreCoordinator implementation to test for iCloud support or not and a couple of other small changes.

However now when I check to see if the sqlite file exists and copy the pre-populated sqlite file if it doesn't I get the following error at

```
[psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData] options:options error:&persistentStoreError];
```

> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  An error occured while setting up the ubiquity integration: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134316 "The ubiquity container does not appear to match this persistent store, it is possible this is caused by switching to a different iCloud account, or logging out of iCloud entirely. The store should be re-opened with read-only attributes or removed from iCloud syncing permanently." UserInfo=0x1cb590 {storeUUID=31381598-EAFA-4550-9B96-F501800974D5, containerUUID=E3A8DC7D-41FD-405A-8D8A-C06C8B467CA2, NSLocalizedDescription=The ubiquity container does not appear to match this persistent store, it is possible this is caused by switching to a different iCloud account, or logging out of iCloud entirely. The store should be re-opened with read-only attributes or removed from iCloud syncing permanently.}

Is this because there are still references in iCloud to a different Core Data sqlite file or transaction log files? If so how would I remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to copy a pre-created Core Data store to the ubiquity container. The old way to do this was to create an SQLite file on the Simulator/device/computer and copy it into it's place on first run. If you use iCloud, you can't do this any more. iCloud works by each device receiving a list of changes as "transaction logs", which it then applies to it's own SQLite store. It needs to know what's changed, and getting a .sqlite file in one lump won't tell it that.

The iCloud way to do this is either:

- Create the initial data from inside your code (e.g. an `insertStartData:` method). You could add it from a plist, or whatever you like. You'll have to check that the data isn't already there first.
- Use `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error` to copy your initial store across.

[Here's the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html)

> You should not seed initial content with a prepackaged database file. Instead, you should create the default items in code, or use NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error: method to migrate a prepackaged database to the required location.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, I only need to import a list of countries(200 & something) along with their lat&long double's into coredata on first startup, would a plist be more efficient than bundling sqlite file and using migratePersistentStore?

Comment: Yeah, a plist would be much easier. Remember to check that it hasn't already been imported.

Comment: Hi, what methods would you use to test the store needs to be added on first run, also, I have a JSON file of nested data - whats the best method to use?